# How to save the excel file using excel dart package?

Tags: excel, flutter, file, dart

I'm trying to implement a function which could select an excel file from phone's storage, edit some values and then finally save it using [excel dart package](https://pub.dev/packages/excel#saving-xlsx-file). My function :

```
Future<void> createExcel() async {
   File file = await selectFile() //this is working fine
   
   //setting some configurations for excel
    var bytes = file!.readAsBytesSync();
    var excel = Excel.decodeBytes(bytes);
    Sheet sheetObject = excel['Sheet1'];
    
   //Updating excel values logic
   for(int i = 1; i<1000; ++i){
     var cell = sheetObject.cell(CellIndex.indexByString("A$i"));
     cell.value = 8; // dynamic values support provided;
   }

    //saving excel
    excel.encode()!.then((onValue) {   //this line is giving error: "The method 'then' isn't defined for the type 'List'. "
        File(join(file!.path))
        ..createSync(recursive: true)
        ..writeAsBytesSync(onValue);
    });

}
```

I couldn't be able to use **.then()** with **excel.encode()** Is there any way to solve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sounds like... your encode method returns a `LIST` and not a `Future<List>`... so put your excel.encode direct in your writeAsBytesSync method

like this:

```
     Future<void> createExcel() async {
   File file = await selectFile() //this is working fine
   
   //setting some configurations for excel
    var bytes = file!.readAsBytesSync();
    var excel = Excel.decodeBytes(bytes);
    Sheet sheetObject = excel['Sheet1'];
    
   //Updating excel values logic
   for(int i = 1; i<1000; ++i){
     var cell = sheetObject.cell(CellIndex.indexByString("A$i"));
     cell.value = 8; // dynamic values support provided;
   }

    //saving excel
    File(join(file!.path))
    ..createSync(recursive: true)
    ..writeAsBytesSync(excel.encode()!);
  }
```

Comment: Worked! thanks , this also worked for me "file!.writeAsBytesSync(excel.encode()!)" . I want to know why these things happens even using the same code from documentation. These type, argument, parameter errors always comes to me ;/

Comment: documentation sample code was not updated maybe...

Comment: @MauriceRaguse I am getting an error at 'File(join(' It says that The function 'join' isn't defined.

Comment: how to add cellstyle for first row in this example